# Parse order fun! Getting a stashed Assets image resized using CE Image inside a plugin parameter

Tags: assets, parse-order, ce-image

Alright, let's see if I can explain this correctly:

- I am using Assets to store images to S3
- CE Image is being used to manipulate the images and save/serve them from S3
- I use stash to try and stay DRY and keep things easier to maintain

So far everything is working great on the site, we're ready to launch, and all humming along... Until I tried to use the SocialEEsta plugin to help spit out share icons.

Here is my model:

```
{!-- SINGLE VARIBLES --}
{exp:stash:set
  parse_tags="no"
  trim="yes"
}
  {stash:share_image_url}
    {exp:ce_img:pair
      src="{cf_featured_image:url}"
      width="800"
      height="450"
      crop="yes"
      allow_scale_larger="yes"
      hide_relative_path="yes"
      cache_dir="cache/img/products/shared/"
    }
      {aws_url}
    {/exp:ce_img:pair}
  {/stash:share_image_url}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Here is my viewModel that gets all of my vars:

```
{exp:stash:set
  name="hero"
  output="no"
  parse_conditionals="no"
  parse_tags="no"
  parse_vars="yes"
}
  {stash:embed:partials:hero_banner}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

This is in my partial:

```
{exp:socialeesta:pinit url="{current_url}" media="{stash:share_image_url}" count="none" description="{stash:page_body}"}
```

Is this even possible?

I've tried:
 - parse_tags="no/yes"
 - parse_vars="yes"
 - process="start/end"
 - adding parse="inward" to the plugin tag
 - adding random to the plugin tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welp, after even more testing an hair pulling I sorted it out. I forgot to set parse_tags="yes" on the exp:stash:set... d'oh!

Model

```
{!-- SINGLE VARIBLES --}
{exp:stash:set
  parse_tags="yes"
  trim="yes"
}
  {stash:share_image_url}
    {exp:ce_img:pair
      src="{cf_featured_image:url}"
      width="800"
      height="450"
      crop="yes"
      allow_scale_larger="yes"
      hide_relative_path="yes"
      cache_dir="cache/img/products/shared/"
    }
      {aws_url}
    {/exp:ce_img:pair}
  {/stash:share_image_url}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Here is my viewModel that gets all of my vars:

```
{exp:stash:set
  name="hero"
  output="no"
  parse_conditionals="no"
  parse_tags="no"
  parse_vars="no"
}
  {stash:embed:partials:hero_banner}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

This is in my partial:

```
{exp:socialeesta:pinit url="{current_url}" media="http:{stash:share_image_url}" count="none" description="{stash:page_body}"}
```